# Simulate Webjob Shutdown for debugging

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

Scenario:
I have hooked up the Web job with a CancellationToken and need to simulate shutdown to see if the cancellation is being processed successfully. I've tried the Ctrl + C combination but the cancellation did not fire. What is the correct way of simulating this shutdown for debugging purposes?

Comment: You can just wait for X seconds and cancel the token ?

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for the pointer. I ended up creating a new cancelationtoken wrapped in the DEBUG pre-processor and was able to test it.

Comment: Post your answer if you have time, someone else could be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is debug code, did it with a bit of a hack. The issue in my case is, the CancellationToken was being passed by a framework call and did not allow access to the CancellationTokenSource.

```
private async Task InitializeEventProcessing(CancellationToken ctx)
    {

#if DEBUG
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        ctx = cts.Token;
#endif
     .
     .
     .
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't really like the other answer, so here is what I did...

The built in `WebJobsShutdownWatcher` looks for an environment variable WEBJOBS_SHUTDOWN_FILE and watches for changes.

If you configure the debug settings to provide a file name for that environment variable, then all you have to do create that file(contents don't matter) and it will follow the same shutdown path as if it is deployed.

Of course you have to delete it afterward, or add a build step to delete it on debug or something, but at least it's executing the same code as graceful shutdown on the host.